# How are you able to get an A2DP bluetooth profile to work using bluetooth 4.0 (BLE)? Do I need an AptX codec?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, a2dp, avrcp

I’ve been reading that BLE only works with a small amount of profiles (based on GATT and other smaller use specific profiles), but I’ve seen many Bluetooth 4.0 headphones that use A2DP available on the market (examples below). However, all of the bluetooth 4.0 headphones have one thing in common…use of the aptX codec. What is aptX and is it way to get A2DP to work as a profile using bluetooth 4.0? Is there another way anyone knows about to pass audio and remote control commands to a mobile device over BLE?

[Example 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CTKMJ8U)

[Example 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FIL0T3O)

Answer (score 0):

BLE will not support A2DP. from the specifications provided on the link, these devices are dual mode(supports both BT Classic and BT LE).APTx is a codec and provides better sound quality than SBC but SBC is mandatory to support in A2DP profile.